# DocumentSnapshot returns null in flutter while passing it as named argument of a class

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store all the data to local map. But the problem I am facing is `allPosts.add(Post.fromSnapshot(snapshot))` does not add data to the List allPosts. I tried to store `snapshot.data` to a map variable but it also returns null. I commented the problem in code also.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class PostServices{
  List<Post> allPosts=[];
  Firestore _firestore=Firestore.instance;
  Future<List<Post>> posts()=>
      _firestore.collection("Post").getDocuments().then((snap){
        snap.documents.map((snapshot)=>
            allPosts.add(Post.fromSnapshot(snapshot))
        );
        print(snap.documents.length);   //it gives the number of documents
        print(allPosts);      //it returns [] i.e. the List<Post> is empty
        return allPosts;
      });
}


class Post{
  String _id;
  String _description;
  // int _likes;
  String _photoURL;
  Post();
  String get id=>_id;
  String get description=>_description;
  // int get likes=>_likes;
  String get photoURL=>_photoURL;

  Post.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
  {
    Map data=snapshot.data;
    _id=data['userId'];
    _description=data['desc'];
    // _likes=data['like'];
    _photoURL=data['image'];
  }
}


class PostProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  List<Post> _post=[];
  PostServices _postServices=PostServices();

  PostProvider(){
    _getAllPosts();
  }

  List<Post> get post=>_post;

  void _getAllPosts() async{
    _post=await _postServices.posts();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The another file from where I am calling the provider class is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'Providers/post_provider.dart';

class TesterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var postProvider=Provider.of<PostProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("News Feed"),
      ),
      body:Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Click to check", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),),
        onPressed: (){
                 print("Hello");
                 print(postProvider.post.length);
                  PostServices().posts();
        },
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Touseef, your `Post` model doesn't look right. I think it should be returning `Post` object if you're trying to save it to `allPosts` list. Can you try the code below?

```
class PostServices{
  List<Post> allPosts=[];
  Firestore _firestore=Firestore.instance;
  Future<List<Post>> posts()=>
      _firestore.collection("Post").getDocuments().then((snap){
        snap.documents.map((snapshot)=>
            allPosts.add(postFromSnapsot(snapshot))
        );
        print(snap.documents.length);   //it gives the number of documents
        print(allPosts);      //it returns [] i.e. the List<Post> is empty
        return allPosts;
      });

  Post postFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Post(
      _id: snapshot.data['id'],//not sure what your column name is, use your column name here
      _description: snapshot.data['description'],
      _photoURL: snapshot.data['photoURL'],
    );
  }
}

class Post{
  String _id;
  String _description;
  // int _likes;
  String _photoURL;

  Post({this._id, this._description, this._photoURL});

  String get id=>_id;
  String get description=>_description;
  // int get likes=>_likes;
  String get photoURL=>_photoURL;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but did not work for me. I tried to return stream also but nothing worked. Please suggest me any alternative way. Thank you.